How to get rid of CURSOR if every FETCH needs a SELECT based on previous result
We have a couple of tables, let's call them Sections and SectionTimeWindows. Sections table contains data about sections of 'movement', which starts at a place, ends at a place and has a type. The type is important, because it determines how much time will a section take - every section type has a set of time windows and the window determines the running time of a section based on when we arrive at the section.
We need a new table, where StopTimes are recorded, provided we know a DepartureTime. We start with a stop at the beginning of the first section at StopTime=DepartureTime, then determine RunningTime for every section based on previous StopTime, and we insert the StopTime as new row. This means, that the RunningTime and therefore the StopTime values are based on results computed for previous row(s).
Our current implementation uses a CURSOR to iterate over Sections, keep current StopTime, probe the relevant window for next RunningTime, add RunningTime to StopTime and INSERT.
A simplified version of our code is this:
CREATE TABLE #Sections
(
    SectionID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    SectionTypeID INT,
    StartPlaceID INT,
    EndPlaceID INT,
    [Order] INT,
);

CREATE TABLE #SectionTimeWindows
(
    SectionTimeWindowID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    SectionTypeID INT,
    WindowStart INT,
    WindowEnd INT,
    RunningTime INT,
)

CREATE TABLE #StopTimes
(
    StopTimeID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    PlaceID INT,
    IncommingSectionID INT NULL,
    ArrivalTime INT,
    [Order] INT,
)

INSERT INTO #Sections (SectionTypeID, StartPlaceID, EndPlaceID, [Order]) VALUES 
    (1, 10, 20, 1),
    (1, 20, 30, 2),
    (1, 30, 40, 3),
    (1, 40, 50, 4),
    (1, 50, 60, 5)

INSERT INTO #SectionTimeWindows (SectionTypeID, WindowStart, WindowEnd, RunningTime) VALUES
    (1, 00*60, 09*60, 30), -- from midnight to 9AM 
    (1, 09*60, 18*60, 50), -- from 9AM to 18AM    
    (1, 18*60, 24*60, 5) --- dtto

DECLARE @Departure INT = 8 * 60 -- the departure of the whole movement. Used at the first iteration only. This is a parameter of this (when this is converted to SP)
DECLARE @CurrentTime INT = NULL -- the stop time variable hold the current result of current interation
DECLARE @RunningTime INT = NULL -- the current iteration running time, based on window

DECLARE @CurrentSectionID INT;
DECLARE @CurrentSectionTypeID INT;
DECLARE @CurrentStartPlaceID INT;
DECLARE @CurrentEndPlaceID INT;

DECLARE @Order INT = 1;

DECLARE rowIterator CURSOR
    LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT SectionID, SectionTypeID, StartPlaceID, EndPlaceID
        FROM #Sections
        ORDER BY [Order]
OPEN rowIterator;

WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM rowIterator INTO @CurrentSectionID, @CurrentSectionTypeID, @CurrentStartPlaceID, @CurrentEndPlaceID
    IF (@@FETCH_STATUS <> 0) BREAK;
        
    IF (@CurrentTime is null) -- First iteration, we have no previous results, need @Departure as first StopTime
    BEGIN 
        SET @CurrentTime = @Departure
        INSERT INTO #StopTimes (PlaceID, IncommingSectionID, ArrivalTime, [Order]) 
        VALUES (@CurrentStartPlaceID, NULL, @CurrentTime, @Order)
    END

    SET @Order = @Order + 1
    -- Fetch @RunningTime from signle window where @CurrentStopTime is in the window and SectionType matches
    SELECT TOP 1 @RunningTime = RunningTime FROM #SectionTimeWindows 
        WHERE SectionTypeID = @CurrentSectionTypeID AND WindowStart <= @CurrentTime AND @CurrentTime < WindowEnd
    -- Add @RunningTime to @CurrentStopTime. This value will be used in next iteration to get new window
    SET @CurrentTime = @CurrentTime + @RunningTime
    INSERT INTO #StopTimes (PlaceID, IncommingSectionID, ArrivalTime, [Order])
        VALUES (@CurrentEndPlaceID, @CurrentSectionID, @CurrentTime, @Order)
END
CLOSE rowIterator
DEALLOCATE rowIterator

SELECT StopTimeID, PlaceID, IncommingSectionID, 
ArrivalTime / 60 as Hours, ArrivalTime % 60 as Minutes,
ArrivalTime - LAG(ArrivalTime) Over (ORDER BY [Order]) as RunningTime
FROM #StopTimes


DROP TABLE #Sections
DROP TABLE #StopTimes
DROP TABLE #SectionTimeWindows

The real structure is a bit more complicated, the data is also grouped by MovementID and apart from the ArrivalTime, we also track several other properties. We may also wait at a StopPlace, which delays the departure to the next section as well. But this is the gist of it.
The real procedure takes up to 6 hours to compute (real Sections table has around 10^6 rows and SectionTimeWindows table has around 10^7 rows). The issue is most likely the SELECT in every FETCH iteration, but I don't know how to JOIN the SectionTimeWindows if I don't have the Probe to do it.
I've tried to approach the problem using LAG, but got nowhere, as the previous row's ArrivalTime is a result of it's previous row's ArrivalTime recursively. I have the same issue with SUM OVER(PARTITION..RANGE..), but again, I have no idea how to JOIN the window. I would need some kind of SUM(SELECT...WHERE PROBE)...
Is there any way to remove this kind of CURSOR? And if not, is there any way to speed up the SELECT TOP 1?
Here is a hopefully more clear explanation of what the function should do:

We have a set of Sections, every section has a set of SectionTimeWindows where every window defines an interval of time for which a RunningTime in a Section is valid. We stop between sections. If we arrive at the section between 00:00 and 9:00, the RunningTime in section is 30 minutes; if we arrive between 9:00 and 18:00, the RunningTime is 50 minutes etc
The arrival to a Section is recorded in StopTimes table, ArrivalTime column. There are N+1 StopTimes as we stop before the first section as well.
The arrival to a section is determined by ArrivalTime to previous section + RunningTime given by the SectionTimeWindows where ArrivalTime in previous section falls into a window <WindowStart, WindowEnd)


if you need information from the prior row, why not use LAG? What version of SQL Server are you using?

Do you have proper indexes so the TOP 1 thing at least doesn't trawl through whole table? How many SectionTimeWindows rows is it per each Sections? Is it always 3

Some of this logic seems convoluted. For example you have the clause WindowStart <= @Probe. @Prode is define as @StopTime and  @StopTime is defined as @Departure. Why not just WindowStart <= @Departure?

Also your query with a TOP has no ORDER BY so the value assigned to @RunningTime will be completely arbitrary. I feel like you need to take a step back here and explain the actual logic to get from A to B here.

It seems intervals of a SectionTypeID in the #SectionTimeWindowstable never intersect. You need no Top(1).

@ThomA The information is from the prior result row of StopTimes, not from prior row of input Sections;
The @StopTime changes in every iteration. @Departure is used only in the first iteration and @Probe is just an alias. I've added @Probe for brevity and because in the real implementation, the @Probe is needed as there is @StopTime and @WaitTime as well. It could be WindowStart <= @StopTime, yes.
The TOP 1 does not need any ORDER BY because for every SectionTypeID there is only a single window where @Probe would fall in. It is there because it makes the select faster.

@siggemannen Yes, the index is there, otherwise the whole thing would be useless. The issue I think is that even with index, the iterative nature of the cursor makes it slower as it would do insane amount of index Seeks, and I think if join would be possible, the index Scan would actually be better here, possibly?

Without a description of the logic here, I'm not going to attempt writing a set based attempt. Like i mentioned, there's a lot of "muddying of the water" (@Probe = @StopTime = @Departure = 8 * 60 is just an example). If you take the time to explain the goal, then working out a set-based solution will likely be much easier.

Doesn't @Probe increase all the time though? There should be some sort of reset when it comes to next day? Or am i missing something?

@ThomA I've updated the code a bit and added comments and description of what the logic should do.

@siggemannen In reality it does, there is a parent entity which resets the time counter. I've omitted it as it is not relevant and I can PARTITION the the set based implementation of this, if one is possible.

It matters, because after a while you will get no hits on #windows table, which skewers results, at least when i test. Btw, it's probably silly, but did you use: SET NOCOUNT ON when executing this procedure? Such cursors takes forever with this setting OFF. Can this movement stuff span multiple days?

@siggemannen yes, I use SET NOCOUNT ON and yes, in this example, the windows would run out, but in real implementation, there is a modulo function - when we arrive at 24:00, we wrap around to 00:00. Regrettably I cannot show the original code :( I've tried to distill the relevant part for the problem I have.

i'm guessing you modulo this probe-thingy, and keep the endtime as is? Spontanously, i don't think it's easy to move away with the cursor, but do you have to recalc this thing from scratch every day?

@siggemannen I modulo the probe, yes, then I always get a window and always get a RunningTime. The ArrivalTime however increases all the time (no modulo) and may may go up to several days, accumulating all the RunningTimes. We recalc it every time there is a DataMigration from old system, which nowadays is daily. The process takes up to 6 hours (on bad hardware, nothing i can do about. Locally it takes 45 mins)

how many different Window(s) variations are there? Perhaps something can be done there to avoid the select? For example, one could collate the distinct variations and join against that instead

Every Section has its own windows and running times in those windows. The windows themselves (distinct by Start and End) are a few, but the running times change with every section (based on its distance, think streets between intersections and traffic congestion affecting your running time). The table SectionTimeWindows in my example is already a view of a hierarchy of several tables. But in the end, we have a set of windows with RunningTimes for every Section.

Ok, i give up :) Buy a decent comp, create a linked server to it, run the stuff there and then copy it back to the "weak" machine. Dev time is much more expensive than hardware

@siggemannen Hehe, yea, I wish it would be, but we are at big deploy time, so dev time means nothing :( Anyway, thank you very much for trying, I kinda had a gut feeling I have the one CURSOR example where CURSOR removal is...difficult. But I'll try the pre-joining of windows into the cursor suggested by Lajos Arpad below, i think that might help a bit...

The timetable does not depend on the places of stops. Therefore, first we make a separate schedule (timetable) for every SectionTypeId.
From #SectionTimeWindows:



SectionTimeWindowID
SectionTypeID
WindowStart
WindowEnd
RunningTime




1
1
0
540
30


2
1
540
1080
50


3
1
1080
1440
5



To timetable:
Converted to timetable. Part of timetable for SectionTypeId=1. We begin from 8:00.



lvl
Num
SectionTypeID
WindowStart
WindowEnd
RunningTime
hours
minutes




0
null
1
null
480
null
8
0


1
0
1
480
510
30
8
30


2
1
1
510
540
30
9
0


3
2
1
540
590
50
9
50


4
3
1
590
640
50
10
40


5
4
1
640
690
50
11
30


6
5
1
690
740
50
12
20


7
6
1
740
790
50
13
10


8
7
1
790
840
50
14
0


9
8
1
840
890
50
14
50


10
9
1
890
940
50
15
40



Then, join places (ordered by [Order]) to timetable.
Some fiddling with the starting point slightly complicates (confuses) the query.
See example
Test data:



SectionID
SectionTypeID
StartPlaceID
EndPlaceID
Order




1
1
10
20
1


2
1
20
30
2


3
1
30
40
3


4
1
40
50
4


5
1
50
60
5


6
2
11
21
1


7
2
21
31
2


8
2
31
41
3


9
2
41
51
4


10
2
51
61
5






SectionTimeWindowID
SectionTypeID
WindowStart
WindowEnd
RunningTime




1
1
0
540
30


2
1
540
1080
50


3
1
1080
1440
5


4
2
0
600
40


5
2
600
1080
60


6
2
1080
1440
20



with r as( -- recursively create timetable
select 0 lvl, null Num,SectionTypeID
  ,null WindowStart
  ,08*60  as WindowEnd  
  ,null RunningTime
from #SectionTimeWindows w
 where w.WindowStart=(select min(WindowStart) from #SectionTimeWindows w2
                    where w2.SectionTypeId=w.SectionTypeId)
  union all
select lvl+1,coalesce(r.Num,-1)+1,w.SectionTypeID
  ,r.WindowEnd WindowStart
  ,r.WindowEnd+w.RunningTime WindowEnd
  ,w.RunningTime
from r inner join #SectionTimeWindows w 
  on r.SectionTypeId=w.SectionTypeId
    and w.WindowStart<=r.WindowEnd and w.WindowEnd>r.WindowEnd 
-- where lvl<17  -- for debug only
)
select 
   s.SectionTypeID, WindowStart, WindowEnd, RunningTime
  ,case when num is null then StartPlaceID else EndPlaceId end PlaceId
  ,case when num is null then null else SectionId end IncomingSectionId
  ,WindowEnd/60 hours
  ,WindowEnd%60 minutes
from r 
inner join (select *, row_number()over(partition by SectionTypeId order by [Order] )rn
      from #Sections) s 
  on r.SectionTypeId=s.SectionTypeId 
    and (r.Num=(s.rn-1) or (r.num is null and rn=1))
order by s.SectionTypeId,lvl;


Output



SectionTypeID
WindowStart
WindowEnd
RunningTime
PlaceId
Inc.SectionId
hours
minutes




1
null
480
null
10
null
8
0


1
480
510
30
20
1
8
30


1
510
540
30
30
2
9
0


1
540
590
50
40
3
9
50


1
590
640
50
50
4
10
40


1
640
690
50
60
5
11
30


2
null
480
null
11
null
8
0


2
480
520
40
21
6
8
40


2
520
560
40
31
7
9
20


2
560
600
40
41
8
10
0


2
600
660
60
51
9
11
0


2
660
720
60
61
10
12
0



fiddle
Update1.
We can reduce recursion depth.
If window size(WindowEnd-WindowStart)>> RunningTime, we should carefully take rows near WindowStart and WindowEnd by recursion and all other rows generate thru generate_series.
-- timetable with  reduced recursion
with r as(
select 0 lvl, 1 repeatCnt, null Num,SectionTypeID
  ,null WindowStart
  ,08*60  as WindowEnd  
  ,null RunningTime
from #SectionTimeWindows w
 where w.WindowStart=(select min(WindowStart) from #SectionTimeWindows w2
                    where w2.SectionTypeId=w.SectionTypeId)
  union all
select lvl+1
  ,case when (w.WindowEnd-r.WindowEnd)>w.runningTime then -- multy row
      floor((w.WindowEnd-r.WindowEnd)/w.runningTime)
   else 1 
   end repeatCnt
  ,coalesce(r.Num,-1)+1,w.SectionTypeID
  ,r.WindowEnd WindowStart
  ,case when (w.WindowEnd-r.WindowEnd)>w.runningTime then -- multy row
      r.WindowEnd+floor((w.WindowEnd-r.WindowEnd)/w.runningTime)*w.runningTime
   else r.WindowEnd+w.RunningTime 
   end WindowEnd
  ,w.RunningTime
from r inner join #SectionTimeWindows w 
  on r.SectionTypeId=w.SectionTypeId
    and w.WindowStart<=r.WindowEnd and w.WindowEnd>r.WindowEnd 
where lvl<17
)
,ExpandedTimetable as(
  select lvl,repeatCnt,Num,SectionTypeID
    ,WindowStart+RunningTime*(value-1) WindowStart
    ,WindowStart+RunningTime*(value) WindowEnd
    ,WindowStart grStart, WindowEnd grEnd
    ,RunningTime
    ,value n
  from r
  cross apply generate_series(1,r.repeatCnt)tn
  )
 select * from r order by SectionTypeId,lvl;
 -- select * from ExpandedTimeTable order by SectionTypeId,lvl;

  select * 
  ,WindowEnd/60 hours
  ,WindowEnd%60 minutes
  from ExpandedTimeTable order by SectionTypeId,lvl;


Recursion query output is only several rows. Recursin depth is 4.



lvl
repeatCnt
Num
SectionTypeID
WindowStart
WindowEnd
RunningTime




0
1
null
1
null
480
null


1
2
0
1
480
540
30


2
10
1
1
540
1040
50


3
1
2
1
1040
1090
50


4
70
3
1
1090
1440
5


0
1
null
2
null
480
null


1
3
0
2
480
600
40


2
8
1
2
600
1080
60


3
18
2
2
1080
1440
20



Then, we can expand timetable. Every row to repeatNum rows.



lvl
repeatCnt
Num
SectionTypeID
WindowStart
WindowEnd
grStart
grEnd
RunningTime
n




0
1
null
1
null
null
null
480
null
1


1
2
0
1
480
510
480
540
30
1


1
2
0
1
510
540
480
540
30
2


2
10
1
1
540
590
540
1040
50
1


2
10
1
1
590
640
540
1040
50
2


2
10
1
1
640
690
540
1040
50
3


2
10
1
1
690
740
540
1040
50
4


2
10
1
1
740
790
540
1040
50
5


2
10
1
1
790
840
540
1040
50
6


2
10
1
1
840
890
540
1040
50
7


2
10
1
1
890
940
540
1040
50
8


2
10
1
1
940
990
540
1040
50
9


2
10
1
1
990
1040
540
1040
50
10


3
1
2
1
1040
1090
1040
1090
50
1


4
70
3
1
1090
1095
1090
1440
5
1


4
70
3
1
1095
1100
1090
1440
5
2


4
70
3
1
1100
1105
1090
1440
5
3


4
70
3
1
1105
1110
1090
1440
5
4



fiddle

This is basically what I have envisioned - some kind of set-based recursion to backtrack the data. I have tried a version of this idea on our real data (as full solution would require a complete redesign of the SP). The recursion is so deep it fails on recursion limit, as in real data, the RunningTimes are much smaller -> more recursion iterations to compute the timetable -> recursion limit. But I can use the debug filter on lvl to get the first 20 rows the recursive timetable, for testing.

I've been able to make the second part of the query sort of work, it's gives a bit weird results, but I think it's my mistake, I've oversimplified the example in the question too much (ie I've declared that many Sections share a SectionTypeID when in reality every Section has its own SectionTypeID with its own windows) which introduced a logic in the sample data which is not present in the real data and which is kinda used in the join of the timetables with the sections i think.

Nevertheless, I've been able to adjust it a little and get some results, however, even for single movement and limited in the recursion levels, there are just way too many recursions and the table is huge (as it basically contains every possible RunningTime for every possible time we can arrive at the section). The query is unfortunately several orders of magnitude slower. However, the approach is sound and I'm going to explore it a bit more. This answer also shows a way to avoid the cursor as well, so I'm going to mark it. Thank you!

You can significantly reduce the recursion depth. The recursion depth in the minimum is near to the number of rows in the #SectionTimeWindows table.  See an example with a reduced recursion depth.

You can join #Sections with #SectionTimeWindows:
        SELECT S.SectionID, S.SectionTypeID, S.StartPlaceID, S.EndPlaceID, STW.Runtime
        FROM #Sections S
        JOIN #SectionTimeWindows STW
        ON S.SectionTypeID = STW.SectionTypeID
        ORDER BY [Order]

and then loop through the results without searching for the window difference. If you have multiple window records for the same type, then you can SUM(Runtime) AS Runtime and use a GROUP BY.
Also, you can even get rid of your loop by using an insert-select, but then you will need to join the current element with the next and have a left join for in-between element which will be all-null (proving that the next is indeed the next) and inserting the first special record separately. But that's a large change, let me know if the performance issue still persists.
Finally, consider the creation of indexes, which speed up searches.

You mean join the windows at the CURSOR definition and then skip the iterator iterations when the window is incorrect according to CurrentTime? I can try that, I'm not sure how would I show the result though... Edit the question and add the new code in? Also I don't understand the sum of the WindowEnd-WindowStart - RunningTime is whats relevant if my CurrentTime falls into the window. The difference (= lengh of window) is arbitrary (user defined).

The second paragraph is what I have trouble with. I would like to somehow join the previous result row, but since that row is dependent on all the previous result rows, how would I do it? Some sort of recursion? Backtracking function?
The indexes are present, without them the whole CURSOR would be unusably slow anyway. Also there is 'SET NOCOUNT ON'

@DavidCholt the second paragraph is all about aggregation. You can group by and sum. Yes, the fifth depends on the fourth and the fourth depends on the third, you have STW.WindowEnd - STW.WindowStart of the first + STW.WindowEnd - STW.WindowStart of the second which boils down to a SUM().

I think there is a misunderstanding, WindowEnd-WindowStart just gives me WindowSize, which I do not care about. All I care about is RunningTime from the windows. But I tried to join the window records into sections as the select inside of the filter and the logic now skips windows which are not relevant when getting RunningTime... It works, but unfortunately the performance is the same :(

@DavidCholt indeed, my understanding was that WindowEnd - WindowStart is a duration, that these are points in time. Since you are interested in Runtime, we need to use that instead of the subtraction I initially suggested. Edited my answer accordingly.

This is what I've implemented, yes, and it works (as in gives correct results) but the performance is same or slightly lower. But it confirmed for me that the selects inside the CURSOR where not an issue apparently, the problem is elsewhere...

@DavidCholt just out of curiosity: how long does it take to run the query that you can find in my answer?

I didn't do the full run for the whole table, only TOP(3000) movements, but original takes around 6 seconds, and the pre-joined cursor takes 7-8 seconds (both give identical 45k+ results, so that's good). It was still worth it, as it seems the repeated selects in the cursor solution are not the bottleneck. Ill try to explore this path, keeping the cursor, as well, but unfortunately I cannot mark 2 answers as accepted. This was helpful however. Thank you!

@DavidCholt no worries, happy to help.
